# I want to extract information from a message using regex

Tags: java, regex, android-studio

I have an app that listens to an incoming SMS message using the broadcast receiver.

The app only receives messages from a specific sender. I would like to extract certain information from the messages i.e.

- Txn Code
- Date
- Time
- Amount
- Account
- Username

**QAP04N99TG** Confirmed.on **25/1/22** at **1:57** PMKsh**1.00** received from **1123123322** **JOHN DUE MARTIN**. New Account balance is Ksh10.00. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.

I have tried using the below but I only get the Txncode.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\s]|Ksh([0-9,.]+)\s|from\s([0-9]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+.)$";
        final String string = "QAP04N99TG Confirmed.on 25/1/22 at 1:57 PMKsh1.00 received from 1123123322 JOHN DUE MARTIN. New Account balance is Ksh10.00. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        if(matcher.find()) {
            String txnCode = matcher.group(1);
            String date = matcher.group(2);
            String time = matcher.group(3);
            String amount = matcher.group(4);
            String account = matcher.group(5);
            String username = marcher.group(6);

            System.out.println(txnCode+date+time+amount+account+username);
        }
    }
}
```

I can only get txnCode.
If you know I can be able to extract all details. Kindly assist.

Comment: You use an alternation `|` to match different parts in the string, and note that there are no 6 groups in total. The last alternation asserts the end of the string `$` but that part does currently not match. Is the order of the data in the string always the same and are all parts always present?

Comment: First of all `if(matcher.find())` should be `while (matcher.find())` but there are other problems in your regex pattern

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/OvZKnY/1) pattern helps?

Answer (score 2):

You can match and capture these bits of information using

```java
^(\w+)\s.*?(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,})\s+at\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}).*?Ksh([0-9,.]+)\s.*?from\s+(\d+)\s+([a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tYJVX2/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s.*?` - a whitespace and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,})` - Group 2: one or two digits, `/`, one or two digits, `/` and then two or more digits
- `\s+at\s+` - `at` enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` - Group 3: one or two digits, `:`, one or two digits
- `.*?Ksh` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible and `Ksh`
- `([0-9,.]+)` - Group 4: one or more digits, `.` or `,` chars
- `\s.*?from\s+` - a whitespace, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, `from` and one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 5: one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([a-zA-Z\s]+)` - Group 6: one or more letters or whitespaces.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/gFu2o9):

```java
String regex = "^(\\w+)\\s.*?(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2,})\\s+at\\s+(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}).*?Ksh([\\d,.]+)\\s.*?from\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([a-zA-Z\\s]+)";
String string = "QAP04N99TG Confirmed.on 25/1/22 at 1:57 PMKsh1.00 received from 1123123322 JOHN DUE MARTIN. New Account balance is Ksh10.00. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while(matcher.find()) {
    String txnCode = matcher.group(1);
    String date = matcher.group(2);
    String time = matcher.group(3);
    String amount = matcher.group(4);
    String account = matcher.group(5);
    String username = matcher.group(6);
    System.out.println(txnCode+">"+date+">"+time+">"+amount+">"+account+">"+username);
}
// => QAP04N99TG>25/1/22>1:57>1.00>1123123322>JOHN DUE MARTIN
```